# SharePoint 2010 and JQuery Tab

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have added JQuery Tab control on my home page but don't know why grey area is coming quite big and not able to find the cause. Tabs are working but there is an ugly gap.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
<asp:Content id="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain">
<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
<div id="ChartTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-Gantt">Gantt Chart</a></li> <li><a href="#tabs-Map">Map Chart</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-Gantt">

        <Web Part Zone 1>

     </div>

    <div id="tabs-Map">

         <Web Part Zone 2>      
    </div>

</div>




<asp:Content id="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">
<style type="text/css">
ul li{
  display: inline;
}

</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#ChartTabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you isolate via Firebug what DOM element is causing the large height?

Comment: Thanks @Roman.. Forgot debugging style sheet in debugger.Found this line is creating problem ,

.ui-helper-clearfix:before, .ui-helper-clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }

If I comment above line it fix the issue. But I'm missing the grey bar color on the tabs :(

Answer (score 0):

Set a height on the list to fix this issue:

```
<ul style="height: 35px; list-style-type: none;"> ... </ul>
```